# Tuleap - Are there keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, issue-tracking, tuleap

When processing many artifacts in a tracker, it is great speed-up if you can stick to the keyboard and do not have to switch between mouse and keyboard. From our evaluation installation it appears that the operation of Tuleap is geared for mouse only. The user guide does not mention keyboard shortcuts.

Is there a way to access key functions/buttons like creating a new artifact or submitting typed changes via keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

There was work on that recently https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=7329
It is available Tuleap 7.3.99.43 or in Tuleap 7.4

The list of current existing shortcuts can be obtained through the '?' key.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, it is possible to change context via keyboard (worked for me), but it is not possible to create or submit an artifact to a tracker yet.